# Why doesn't this extension method work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, extension-methods

In config/initializers:

Created file numeric_helper.rb:

```
  class Numeric
    def my_function
      self + 1
    end 
  end
```

`rails console` throws

```
/home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load': /home/baller/rails/big_pimpin/config/initializers/numeric_helper.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_def, expecting '<' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
endss Nuend my_fself + 1
```

Why does this throw an error?

Working in Rails 3.07.

EDIT: The rest of the error trace:

```
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in 'block in load'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in 'block in load_dependency'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in 'new_constants_in'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in 'load_dependency'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in 'load'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:201:in 'block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in 'each'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in 'block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in 'instance_exec'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in 'run'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in 'block in run_initializers'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in 'each'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in 'run_initializers'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in 'initialize!'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in 'method_missing'
from /home/baller/rails/fann/config/environment.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in 'require'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in 'require_environment!'
from /home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in '<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in 'require'
from script/rails:6:in '<main>'
```

Comment: I don't think you copy and pasted your code exactly since this same code works for me.

Comment: The error message also doesn't match your code: `endss Nuend my_fself + 1`

Comment: No, that's the code. There must be something else going on with the app...

Comment: @BSeven Sorry mate, just open up irb, paste in the code that you pasted above, and then type `6.my_function` ... you'll get 7.

Comment: @James - Done. See edit in post.

Comment: As Jesse Wolgamott suggested, are calling the method on the number?
Because you are monkey patching the Numeric class and all instances of the class will have the method now.

Comment: The syntax error and the message looks really funky. Is there a special character somewhere in the initializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be one or more of the following that fixed it:

1. Restarting the machine
2. Windows line endings on the Ubuntu machine (editing on Windows, running Rails on Ubuntu). Maybe that's why the error message was garbled.